# How to control the display precision of a NumPy float64 scalar?

Tags: numpy, format, ipython, precision

I'm writing a teaching document that uses lots of examples of Python code and includes the resulting numeric output.  I'm working from inside IPython and a lot of the examples use NumPy.

I *want to avoid* print statements, explicit formatting or type conversions. They clutter the examples and detract from the principles I'm trying to explain.

What I know:

- From IPython I can use `%precision` to control the displayed precision of any `float` results.
- I can use `np.set_printoptions()` to control the displayed precision of elements *within* a NumPy array.

What I'm looking for is a way to control the displayed precision of a NumPy `float64` scalar which doesn't respond to either of the above.  These get returned by a lot of NumPy functions.

```
>>> x = some_function()
Out[2]: 0.123456789

>>> type(x)
Out[3]: numpy.float64

>>> %precision 2
Out[4]: '%.2f'

>>> x
Out[5]: 0.123456789

>>> float(x)  # that precision works for regular floats
Out[6]: 0.12

>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

>>> x  # but doesn't work for the float64
Out[8]: 0.123456789

>>> np.r_[x]  # does work if it's in an array
Out[9]: array([0.12])
```

What I want is

```
>>> # some formatting command
>>> x = some_function() # that returns a float64 = 0.123456789
Out[2]: 0.12
```

but I'd settle for:

- a way of telling NumPy to give me `float` scalars by default, rather than `float64`.
- a way of telling IPython how to handling a `float64`, kind of like what I can do with a `repr_pretty` for my own classes.

Comment: Does `x.item()` help?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, but no more than `float(x)` which is probably more descriptive. However `.item()` can be tacked on the end rather than having to wrap the expression.

Answer (score 2):

IPython has formatters (`core/formatters.py`) which contain a dict that maps a type to a format method.  There seems to be some knowledge of NumPy in the formatters but not for the `np.float64` type.

There are a [bunch of formatters](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html), for HTML, LaTeX etc. but `text/plain` is the one for consoles.

We first get the IPython formatter for console text output

```
plain = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
```

and then set a formatter for the `float64` type, we use the same formatter as already exists for `float` since it already knows about `%precision`

```
plain.for_type(np.float64, plain.lookup_by_type(float))
```

Now

```
In [26]: a = float(1.23456789)

In [28]: b = np.float64(1.23456789)

In [29]: %precision 3
Out[29]: '%.3f'

In [30]: a
Out[30]: 1.235

In [31]: b
Out[31]: 1.235
```

In the implementation I also found that `%precision` calls `np.set_printoptions()` with a suitable format string.  I didn't know it did this, and potentially problematic if the user has already set this.  Following the example above

```
In [32]: c = np.r_[a, a, a]

In [33]: c
Out[33]: array([1.235, 1.235, 1.235])
```

we see it is doing the right thing for array elements.

I can do this formatter initialisation explicitly in my own code, but a better fix might to modify IPython `code/formatters.py` line 677

```
    @default('type_printers')
    def _type_printers_default(self):
        d = pretty._type_pprinters.copy()
        d[float] = lambda obj,p,cycle: p.text(self.float_format%obj)
        # suggested "fix"
        if 'numpy' in sys.modules:
            d[numpy.float64] = lambda obj,p,cycle: p.text(self.float_format%obj)
        # end suggested fix
        return d
```

to also handle `np.float64` here if `NumPy` is included.  Happy for feedback on this, if I feel brave I might submit a PR.